# executing bash scripts from R Shiny

Tags: python, r, bash, shiny

On a HPC cluster, I have created a workflow pipeline. To execute the pipeline, I need to execute `commands.sh`. which basically, has series of bash commands such as

```
module load python
module load java/11.0.8
```

It works as expected when I invoke the file from HPC command line `./commands.sh`

I have created a Shiny app within the same folder, and trying to execute the above command using a button from shiny UI as follows

```
  observeEvent(input$run_extern,{
    system(command = "../commands.sh 2>&1 | tee ../output.log", intern = FALSE, wait = FALSE)
  })
```

I get error,

> line 27: module: command not found

It seems that the environment from Rshiny is different from when I use the HPC. How do solve this ? Even a python solution would be helpful

Comment: did you read everything [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/system) make sure you're using the system command correctly?

Comment: you should debug by trying just the simplest bash command and make sure that works, i.e. `system("ls")`, always try to isolate the problem

Comment: oh but you aren't even calling it the same, try `"./../commands.sh 2>&1 | ..."`. Reading it better the problem lies somewhere in the R system command is trying to call this `module load` but it doesn't work. I would look into that. How does this module command work? I don't know, research!

Comment: I will check, but in regards to module load functions, these are something related to lmod that is setup on HPC which makes loading the most common softwares easy for users